# Regex in SQL query - REMOVE AFTER

Tags: sql, database, db2

**GOAL**

I want to remove with regex in SQL query everything after the colon, can someone help me to mount this query? I made several attempts but without success ...

**Normal query**

[image]

**Remove with Regex**

[image]

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
SRV
SRV
SRV
SRV2
SRV2
SRV2
...
```

**ATTEMPT**

```
select regexp_replace(
hostname,'([^,]+), (\1(, |$))+', '\1\3')
from hosts;
```

Comment: Your attempted regex does not really tie up with your example. Please edit either your example input and desired result, or explain what you think your regex is trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it simpler to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061492.html

e.g.

```
WITH hosts(hostname) AS ( 
    VALUES ('SRV:MD1'),('SRV:MD2'),('SRV2:GW2') 
)
SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(hostname,'(.+):',1,1,'',1)
FROM
    hosts
```

which will return

```
 1
 ----
 SRV
 SRV
 SRV2
```